# Information about the device files: /dev

Tags: linux, filesystems

```
ls /dev
```

command lists the device files.

How to know the **associated drivers**/major_numbers/minor_numbers with those device files?

Answer (score 7):

`ls -l /dev` will give you the major and minor numbers, e.g.

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Apr  4 07:54 /dev/ttyS0
```

has major number 4 and minor number 64.

Then you can look at `/proc/devices` to look up the major number.  In this example we have a character device (`c` at the start of the line) with major number `4`, and in `/proc/modules` we find

```
Character devices:
...
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
```

Allocation of minor numbers is device-dependent.

Some devices are driven from core kernel code (e.g. `tty`), whereas others are managed by loadable modules (e.g. `rfcomm`).  You could try looking in `/proc/modules` for a matching module; alternatively look in `/proc/kallsyms` for the module name.  You'll get lots of results, but the key thing to look for is the presence or absence of a string in square brackets.  For example, `grep tty /proc/kallsyms` gives

```
0000000000000000 t tty_drivers_open
0000000000000000 t show_tty_range
0000000000000000 t show_tty_driver
...
```

whereas `grep rfcomm /proc/kallsyms` gievs

```
0000000000000000 t rfcomm_apply_pn  [rfcomm]
0000000000000000 t rfcomm_dlc_debugfs_open  [rfcomm]
0000000000000000 t rfcomm_dlc_debugfs_show  [rfcomm]
```

`[rfcomm]` indicates that the code is in the `rfcomm` module, whereas `tty` is in the kernel itself and not in a module, so nothing appears in square brackets.

This method is not definitive but should give you some idea as to where the controlling code lives.

Comment: Thanks. Now for the (char)node, i got its major number, minor number, associated device name. How to find the associated device driver program?

Comment: Yes I got some idea. But the information i know are major number, minor number, device name: which is not used in finding the device driver program (modules), using the /proc/modules or /proc/kallsyms right?

Comment: The major number is used to look up the device name in `/proc/modules`, and the device name is used to look for modules or kernel symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-l` option, which displays the numbers.

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 Jan 22 10:34 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 Dec  4 13:24 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 Dec  4 13:24 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  3 Dec  4 13:24 /dev/sda3
...
```

`stat` displays these as well (as "Device type")

```
$ stat /dev/sda
  File: '/dev/sda'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 3431        Links: 1     Device type: 8,0
...
```